# Some... some... and others.... Some

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-pattern

> The place is alive with campers in tents, hitch-pulls and fifth wheeltrailers, and assorted motor homes. Families with small children andteens are running everywhere. **Some** are on the way to the themepark, **some** are headed to the pool, and **others** are playing basketball. **Some** are riding on the gas-powered golf carts with the preteens andteens driving! Scarrry!

*As the 5th Wheel Turns: The Sophomore Year, J.R. Swaim, 2010*

Hello, everyone. I can understand the pattern "some some and others", but here another "some" is used after.  I'm wondering if it is logical if all the members have been mentioned with the pattern previously？

Comment: It's fine. It gives the impression of remembering one more category after the ordinary ones because it has special interest. One alternative is "still others", but that would have the opposite effect ("yet another similar case").

Comment: Thank you, Luke.